# Semantics of reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I've stumbled along the following code:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int x = 8;
  void *w = &x;
  bool val = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x);
  bool *z = static_cast<bool *>(w);
  std::cout << "z (" << z << ") is " << *z << ": " << std::bitset<8>(*z) << "\n";
  std::cout << "val is " << val << ": " << std::bitset<8>(val) << "\n";
}
```

With -O3, this produced output:

```
z (0x7ffcaef0dba4) is 8: 00001000
val is 1: 00000001
```

However, with -O0, this produced output:

```
z (0x7ffe8c6c914c) is 0: 00000000
val is 1: 00000001
```

I know that dereferencing `z` invokes undefined behavior, and is why we are seeing inconsistent results. However, it seems dereferencing the `reinterpret_cast` into `val` is not invoking undefined behavior, and reliably produces {0,1} values.

Via (https://godbolt.org/z/f6s11Kr96), we see that gcc for x86 produces:

```
        lea     rax, [rbp-16]
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        test    al, al
        setne   al
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-9], al
```

The effect of the `test` `setne` instructions is to convert non 0 values to 1 (and keep 0 values at 0). Is there some rule that states that `reinterpret_cast`ing from `void *` to `const unsigned char *` should have this behavior?

Comment: Conversions `signed <-> unsinged` and `small type <-> big type` is a task of `static_cast`: `bool val = static_cast<const unsigned char>(x);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Accessing* (i.e. reading) the value of `z` (not merely dereferencing itself) causes undefined behavior because it is an aliasing violation. (`z` points to an object of type `int`, but the access is through an lvalue of type `bool`)

Access through a lvalue of type `unsigned char` is specifically exempt from being an aliasing violation. (see [[basic.lval]/11.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr#basic.lval-11.3))

However, technically, it is still not specified what the result of accessing the `int` object through a `unsigned char` lvalue should be. The intent is that it gives the first byte of the object representation of the `int` object, but the standard currently is defective in not specifying that behavior. The paper [P1839](https://wg21.link/p1839) attempts to resolve this defect.

After reading this first byte from the object representation as a `unsigned char` value you convert it implicitly to `bool` when initializing `bool val` from it. The conversion from `unsigned char` to `bool` is a conversion of *values*, not reinterpretation of object representation. It is specified that a zero value is converted to `false` and anything else to `true`. (see [[conv.bool]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.bool))

Whether you cast through `void*` explicitly or directly cast the `int*` to `unsigned char*` or `bool*` doesn't matter at all. `reinterpret_cast` between pointers is actually specified to be equivalent to `static_cast<void*>` followed by `static_cast` to the target pointer type. (In your code `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` are interchangeable.)

Comment: Thanks for all these details! So (after P1839), we should expect `val` to be true if the first byte of `x` is nonzero, and zero otherwise (e.g. 0, 256).

Comment: @byrnesj1 Yes, in in practice this was always how it works. Of course how the value of the `int` object relates to the value of the first byte in the object representation is implementation-defined and typically depends at least on endianess. It is also possible e.g. for `int` to have bits that don't participate in the value representation. In that case it may be impossible to predict the result from the `int` value.

Comment: @byrnesj1 For example on a typical big-endian architecture it wouldn't matter which value between 0 and 256 (and beyond until you get into the highest byte) you choose. They would all result in `false`. Only the highest bits would matter.

Answer (score 6):

Reading the value of `*z` causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation (C++20 [basic.lval]/11) . The expression has type `bool` but the object at the memory location has type `int`. Only certain pairs of types are permitted to be aliased, and bool to int is not one of those.

The `val` part of the code is not UB because `const unsigned char` is allowed to alias other types. The initializer for `val` will produce an `unsigned char` value whose memory representation is the same as the contents of the first byte of `x`.

Then, that result is converted (not reinterpreted) to `bool` producing either `false` if 0 or `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior.

According to `-fsanitize=undefined`:

```
/app/example.cpp:9:41: runtime error: load of value 8, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
/app/example.cpp:9:70: runtime error: load of value 8, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vM5MxT4Md

In particular, `-fsanitize=undefined` is complaining that `bool` should hold either `true` or `false` and anything else is UB. (I believe the bit representation of `true` and `false` are implementation-defined.)

Comment: Yeah, the dereferencing of `z` is undefined. From what I've seen compilers expect bools to have bit representations of 0, 1 . This assumption is fine so long as the source code does not subvert the type system (as is done here). However, the `reinterpret_cast` to `const unsigned char *` coerces the values back to 0, 1 and I was wondering what sort of trickery this was.

Comment: The cast to raw bytes is, I think, OK. Generally `reinterpret_cast` is so easy to screw up that I avoid it when I can. It’s much easier to do safely do similar things with `memcpy` (and now `std::bitcast`) and the compiler will optimize it away

Answer (score 0):

As for [expr.reinterpret.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)

> `reinterpret_­cast<T>(v)`
>
> 7. An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.58 When a prvalue v of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv `T`”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.
>
>    [Note 6: Converting a pointer of type “pointer to `T1`” that points to an object of type `T1` to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T2` is an object type and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. — end note].

The expression `bool val = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x);` is a valid code.